# Digital signatures in a smart card: Why have two certificates, one for authentication and the other for non-repudiation (signing)?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, smartcard

Update: reading itext whitepaper on using smart cards to sign and have the following question:

Digital signatures in a smart card:  Why have two certificates, one for authentication and the other for non-repudiation?  Why can't one certificate be used for both since both authentication and non-repudiation certificates uses private keys to encrypt and public key to decrypt.  Is it because the "authentication certificate" contains sensitive info?

It's said that the authentication signatures allows the card to prove his identity and also the certificate contains privacy-sensitive information such as gender, date of birth, and national number.  The non-repudiation signature is used for to generate electronic signatures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It is about programming when I'm reading the 154 pages of technical itext white paper (which have code) and don't understand certain concepts, and so I ask.  I ask questions to fill in my knowledgebase.  It's not pleasurable to program without understanding some background stuff to what I'm reading.  After I read the explaination, I feel as though the cloud just opened up.  Big difference between know and not to know.

Comment: For sure, but programming is not the *topic* of what you are reading. Security with regards to smart cards is the topic. If you have trouble specifying a language and runtime or IDE then there is  a big chance *you are better off* at one of the other SE sites (which means stackexchange :P ).

Comment: If I post at http://security.stackexchange.com, and if I specify Itext at the bottom, will engineers from Itext and users of Itext see my posting?  If I log into SO and go to SE, my gmail credentials does not automatically transfer, so I wonder if these are completely different sites, which I am inclined to believe, in particular when the domain names are different.  If posting an Itext specific question (since I'm reading the white paper) and these questions don't get seen by itext users/engineers, then it lowers the chance of my questions get answered by people who have specific knowledge.

Comment: actually, i just found out I don't have a SE account; creating one.  So similarly, if I post on SE while most Itext users are on SO and don't have SE accounts, then my question doesn't get seen by itext users is my main concern.

Comment: StackExchange is all of [these sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#). YOu have to create a new user, but you can still login using your stackexchange account (or other login provider). For iText specific questions (which this isn't, you haven't even mentioned iText before) there seems to be an iText mailing list.

Comment: i see:  http://money.stackexchange.com   why didn't stackexchange.com create security.stackoverflow.com instead of security.stackexchange.com and that people automatically have the same account across all, this way, everyone who is in itext would see the question instead of being pigeon holed.

Comment: StackOverflow is a term that is specific to programming. So they created a new domain name and only used the stack part of the name for it. You can create different but coupled identities across SO sites. Furthermore, this way the sites can be administered separately. Usually you only have to login once (or not at all, if your session is still valid).

Comment: I think I should have mentioned "I'm reading itext white paper and need help with understanding this concept" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice to have multiple keys for multiple purposes.

There may be a lot of technical differences and procedural differences:

- Authentication could have the PIN cached while the private key of the non-repudiation (non-rep) certificate could require a PIN to be supplied by the holder for each signature operation.
- One private key could be revoked (e.g. the more sensitive non-rep key) while the authentication key could still be be used.
- Authentication maybe used for longer than the non-rep key.
- The key usage of the non-rep key could be more strict.
- The CA keys of the non-rep key could also have a higher grade of protection.
- It used to be the case that e.g. SSL authentication required different signature (MD5 + SHA-1) or encryption operations. The higher the access to keys, the less secure they will be. Nowadays TLS can be used to have a more regular signature in combination with ephemeral Diffie-Hellman.
- As Eugene has commented, there may be legislature in place that requires separate keys and/or certificate chains for authentication and non-rep.

Even if all the above are not true yet, they may apply in the future. Hence the specific keys for a specific purpose. And note that the above is just out of the top of my head.

Comment: owlstead, how can I find your company info?  What is a "non-rep?"  What do you mean by "The higher the access to keys, the less secure they will be."  New to this stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot find my company info, although I have access to SO, I do this strictly in personal time. Lately I sometimes access SO from work to check up on the state (like now), but that's it. Non-rep is short for non-repudiation. Some attacks, including for instance side channel/timing attacks depend on the way keys are being used; in general having more access to the modular exponentiation (as required for encryption) will give an attacker more control, so it may be deemed less secure.

Comment: You can add legal requirements to the list as well - there was a similar question here on SO and there was a reference to one of those EU requirements. I can't find the question now, but such requirements do exist.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Yeah true. I don't know how those regulations have been influenced by the technical reasons, but they are certainly there.

Comment: Owlstead, makes sense.  Thanks.  What is SO by the way?

Comment: @user3769040 StackOverflow :) Note that I've flagged this for transfer to [IT-security](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Seriously, my question has nothing to do with IT-Security as it has to do with Itext.  NOBODY or very little people from IT-Security would know about itext nor are they reading the itext paper.  I see lots of posts on the right side that deals with PDF / itext, and they are also on StackOverFlow.  I personally object to moving my question to the security part of SE.  Doesn't make logical sense where other itext users don't see my question as they themselves may have the same question as they read the 154 page white paper.  Don't get me wrong, I totally love your answer to my question; useful.

Comment: I think I should have mentioned "I'm reading itext white paper and need help with understanding this concept" .. I read my original question again.. yep.  Sounds like a security question.  Okay, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: **I** think we should stop this discussion. Your question clearly isn't a programming question, even if it is about iText. The fact that you could ask this question and I could answer without even mentioning iText is clearly reflecting this. But you have your answer, and you got help about navigating the SE sites. Please take a look at the IT related sites so you know where you can best get answers. A lot of top cryptographers are at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) and security profs are at the security site. You get better help there fore these kind of questions.

Comment: I read my original question again.. yep.  Sounds like a security question.  Okay, I got it. Thanks. =)